# Using substring in xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Following on from an earlier question, and this is more about xsl syntax. I want to split part of a URL variable into a new variable in xsl. 
This code works when the variable is sitting part way along a URL. EG:
`http://www.mysite.com/test.aspx?aVar=something&bVar=somethingMore&cVar=yetMoreStill`

```
    <xsl:variable name="testVar" select="substring-after($url, 'bVar=')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($testVar, '&amp;')" />
```

The problem is the variable can sometime sit at the end of the URL (I have no control over this) EG:
`http://www.mysite.com/test.aspx?aVar=something&bVar=somethingMore`

So the above code fails. Is there away I can allow for both occurrences? The end game is I'm just trying to get the value of bVar no matter where it sits within the URL. Thanks.

Comment: I think Dimitre already answered this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211437/passing-a-url-variable-into-xsl

Comment: Sorry if it seemed that way. I will be using your code in the near future for another project that will present the same issue, but on a lager scale. I accepted the answer below because it answer a short term issue I had. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: @user1001421: The accepted answer has a flaw in it -- as noted by me and other people.

Comment: Please don't mis-represent my comments, Dimitre. I 'noted' that the flaw you pointed out is both easily correctable and entirely avoidable, And it seems to be not an issue for the OP. The accepted answer might not be technically perfect for every case, but it's more than adequate for this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about the following workaround?

```
<xsl:variable name="testVar" select="substring-after($url, 'bVar=')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($testVar, '&amp;'), '&amp;')" />
```

Comment: Genius. A simple, elegant answer. Thanks you very much.

Comment: @user1001421 and VMykyt: This answer is wrong in the general case. Try it with this URL: `http://www.mysite.com/test.aspx?subVar=something&amp;bVar=somethingMore` . See my answer for one correct solution.

Comment: In the unlikely event your field name happens to exist at the end of another field name (and the other one came first), you will unfortunately get the wrong one. A simple fix for that is to adapt your testVar definition to `substring-after(concat('&amp;',substring-after($url, '?')), '&amp;bVar=')`. However, it's pretty easy to avoid that by sensibly choosing your field names.

Answer (score 3):

Try to make use of tokenize (available in XSLT 2.0) like the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="test"><![CDATA[http://www.mysite.com/test.aspx?aVar=something&bVar=somethingMore&cVar=yetMoreStill]]></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="splitURL" select="tokenize($test,'&amp;')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="bvar" select="$splitURL[starts-with(.,'bVar')]"/>
        <out><xsl:value-of select="substring-after($bvar, 'bVar=')"/></out>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I'm I'm stuck with version 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. This is XSLT 1.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="urlResolver">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="'http://www.mysite.com/test.aspx?aVar=something&amp;bVar=somethingMore'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:call-template name="urlResolver">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="'http://www.mysite.com/test.aspx?aVar=something&amp;bVar=somethingMore&amp;cVar=yetMoreStill'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="urlResolver">
    <xsl:param name="input" />
    <xsl:variable name="testVar" select="substring-after($input, 'bVar=')"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($testVar, '&amp;')"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($testVar, '&amp;')" /></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$testVar" /></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

**The currently accepted answer is generally wrong**.

Try it with this URL:

```
http://www.mysite.com/test.aspx?subVar=something&amp;bVar=somethingMore
```

and you get the wrong result: `something`

**This question was already answered...** In case you read the answer you would just reuse it and get your QString from the produced result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:param name="pUrl" select=
     "'http://www.mysite.com/test.aspx?subVar=something&amp;bVar=somethingMore'"/>

     <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:variable name="vrtfQStrings">
           <xsl:call-template name="GetQueryStringParams"/>
         </xsl:variable>

         bVar = "<xsl:value-of select="ext:node-set($vrtfQStrings)/bVar"/>"
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template name="GetQueryStringParams">
      <xsl:param name="pUrl" select="$pUrl"/>

          <xsl:variable name="vQueryPart" select=
          "substring-before(substring-after(concat($pUrl,'?'),
                                            '?'),
                          '?')"/>

          <xsl:variable name="vHeadVar" select=
           "substring-before(concat($vQueryPart,'&amp;'), '&amp;')"/>

           <xsl:element name="{substring-before($vHeadVar, '=')}">
             <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($vHeadVar, '=')"/>
           </xsl:element>

        <xsl:variable name="vRest" select="substring-after($vQueryPart, '&amp;')"/>

        <xsl:if test="string-length($vRest) > 0">
           <xsl:call-template name="GetQueryStringParams">
             <xsl:with-param name="pUrl" select=
             "concat('?', substring(substring-after($vQueryPart, $vHeadVar), 2))"/>
           </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on any XML document (not used), this transformation produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
     bVar = "somethingMore"
```