# Extract URL parameters from XML/XSL

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I'm writing an application to visualize the content of a few databases. This application should be as easy as possible to install and to use, so I decided to use XML files as databases and transform them adequately with XSL through a browser. Right now the XSL files are programmed to create a summary table of every database and by clicking on the first cell of every row a more complete description of the entire entry appears. This means that the page contains every complete description of every record in the database, but this situation slows the loading of the page, which requires up to 5 seconds to load a few hundreds records. Since I plan to expand the databases a lot in the future, this problem is destined to get a lot worse. To reduce the load the next obvious step is to resort to some sort of delayed loading, either by using AJAX or an iframe (not really important which one right now and not the point of the question), but I'm encountering some difficulties. My idea was to directly call a XML file like this:

```
file:///path/to/file/transform.xml?id=23
```

With transform.xml being:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transform.xsl"?>
<content />
```

And transform.xsl being:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="5" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:param name="url" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body><xsl:value-of select="$url" /></body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Right now this is just a proof of concept, but this part is the cornerstone for all that follows and if it doesn't work, then it's useless to proceed further this way.

All I can see in this moment is a blank page. I also tried to change the parameter name to `id`, but the page remains empty.

I know that this can be achieved easily with PHP or other server-side solutions and MySQL would be more efficient, but I really need this application to be usable the very moment the download ends. If my users have to install a *AMP server, they'd probably won't. A public server is also not a solution, since I need this application to be run offline. A JavaScript/jQuery solution on the other hand is perfectly acceptable, since it's client-side.

Edit: Most of my work is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211437/passing-a-url-variable-into-xsl), which seems to work but is quite old and the example contains the URL of an ASP page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since passing URL parameters to XSL seems impractical, I found another way through AJAX. Javascript imports the XML and XSL files, then filters the XML file so that only one element remains, and then applies the XSL file to the remaining XML structure.

For anyone seeking inspiration with similar problems, I'll leave a simplified example of the code I'm using. jQuery is required for this code, but it can work perfectly without.

page.js (copied shamelessly from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_client.asp)):

```
function expand_box(id, tag_to_isolate, XML_file, XSL_file, container) {
    if($('div#' + id).length == 0) { //first opening
        var XML = $.ajax({url: XML_file, async: false, dataType: 'xml'}).responseXML.activeElement;
        var XSL = $.ajax({url: XSL_file, async: false, dataType: 'xml'}).responseXML.activeElement;
        if(XSL.getElementsByTagName('xsl:include').length == 1) { //bonus, see below*
            var XSL_temp = $.ajax({url: 'templates.xsl', async: false, dataType: 'xml'}).responseXML.activeElement;
            $(XSL.getElementsByTagName('xsl:include')).replaceWith(XSL_temp.childNodes);
        }
        XML = $(XML).find(tag_to_isolate + '[id=' + id + ']')[0];
        if (window.ActiveXObject) { // code for IE
            var result = XML.transformNode(XSL);
        }
        else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) { // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
            var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
            xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(XSL);
            var result = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(XML, document);
        }
        $('div#' + panel).append(result);
        //other code here, e.g. to apply all jQuery functions bound to clicks, ...
    }
    $('#' + id).slideDown();
}
```

*Bonus: I found out that javascript xsltProcessor can't handle `xsl:include` tags, so I had to import them manually. The code is quite simple here because I use only one xsl file to contain all shared templates, so the substitution is automatic, but it can be easily adapted to be more flexible.

database.xml (not the same XML file shown above):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<elements>
    <element id="1">
        ...
    </element>
    ...
</elements>
```

transform.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:template match="/elements/element">
        ...
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:include href="templates.xsl" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Depending on the database used, you can create as many matches as needed.

I have to say that my browser warns me synchronous AJAX requests on the main thread are deprecated because of negative effects on the users and will probably be disabled in the future, so the answer could probably be improved, but I chose on purpose to have synchronous requests because everything happens on my computer, the request is fast no matter how big the file is. On a remote server an asynchronous request is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Invocation of a transformation using the xml-stylesheet processing instruction does not provide any way to supply parameters to the transformation. So the parameter will take its default value, which is a zero-length string.

Sorry, but this design isn't going to fly.

I think the only way to do this is to have Javascript code in the HTML page that invokes the transformation programmatically.

One option is to use Saxon-JS rather than relying on the browser-supplied XSLT engine. That will give you access to XSLT 2.0/3.0 features rather than only 1.0, and in 2.0 a stylesheet can access the URI of the source document using the document-uri() function.

Comment: The problem I see with Saxon-JS is that it requires a sort of compilation of XSL files, which means the code will probably become closed-source.

Comment: Yes, the dependency on commercial tools is a factor you have to take into account. You need to decide whether you would rather use commercial tools that are being actively developed in 2017, or free tools that haven't moved forward since 2001.